# Find a shortest path for a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, shortest-path, directed-graph

There is a directed graph `G = [V ; E]` with edge weights `w(u, v)` for `(u, v) ∈ E`.

Suppose the values for `{d[v], π[v]}; v ∈ V` and claims

that these are the length of the shortest path and the predecessor node in

it for `v ∈ V` , how could I verify if this statement is true or false that does not solve the entire shortest path problem from scratch? This is an problem I met with not many ideas in my head ..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a bit unclear, but to clarify:

There's a node `s` in your graph, and that for each vertex `v`:

1. for `v != s`, `pi[v]` is intended to be a node adjacent to `v` that's on a shortest path from `v` to `s`.
2. `d[v]` is intended to store the shortest distance from `v` to `s`.

The problem is to verify, given a `pi`, `d`, that they legitimately contain back-edges and minimal distances.

An easily implemented condition that verifies this is as follows:

```
For each vertex v
   Either:
      v = s and d[v] = 0
   Or:
     d[pi[v]] = d[v] - 1
     d[u] >= d[v] - 1 for each u adjacent to v
     pi[v] is adjacent to v
```

This check runs in O(V + E) time.

Comment: you are on algorithmic question killing spree :(

Comment: Can you guide me more description for your solution? : )

Comment: Here's a hint for a proof: Let d' be the true distance function on the graph. Prove by induction on d'[v] that d[v] = d'[v] and that pi[v] is a vertex adjacent to v that's nearer to s than v.